# Cloudinary Saving Images to database

Tags: cloudinary

Trying to save image name to database using method post while using cloudinary upload widget. Is there any workable examples of this in action?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wait for the upload widget callback, and then save the upload response on your DB with a new POST request. 
Another option would be to use the notification URL.
https://cloudinary.com/blog/webhooks_upload_notifications_and_background_image_processing

Best
--Yakir